# How to get autocomplete textbox value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery auotcomplete functionality. I have applied this to all textboxes starting with particular id and filter the response on the basis of current textbox value. But do not get the value. Below is my code.

```
$("input[id^='TextBoxAssociate']").autocomplete(
    {
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "CreateEditRequest.aspx/GetEmpNames",
                data: "{'empName':'" + $(this).val() + "'}", // here $(this) is ajax context, I want value of current textbox
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (el) {
                        return {
                            label: el.EmpName,
                            value: el.EmpId
                        };
                    }));
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("input[id^='TextBoxAssociate']").autocomplete(
        {
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "CreateEditRequest.aspx/GetEmpNames",
                    data: "{'empName':'" + $(this).val() + "'}", // here $(this) is ajax context, I want value of current textbox
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (el) {
                            return {
                                label: el.EmpName,
                                value: el.EmpId
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
            var label = ui.item.label;
            var value = ui.item.value;
alert('Label : ' + label );
alert('Value : ' + value );
        }
                });
            }
```